# Custom-made archive format question

Tags: filesystems, file-format

I was thinking about developing an own file archive format to use for private projects. The thing is that I am not looking for a solution like 7z or RAR, but I want to make something different, similar to a file system.

Looking at real file system, each has two sections in common in its architecture - information about files stored on disk and actual data of the files, as follows:

```
    ----------------------------
       METADATA  |  FILE DATA
    ----------------------------
```

My question is - how is it possible that these two sections will not overlap? I mean, the FAT STRUCTURE section grows towards the FILE DATA section, while the latter grows towards the end of the disk (partition). How does a file system manage these sections?

This is what I have been trying to figure out for most of the time and any tip would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most file systems operate with clusters or pages or blocks, which have fixed size. In many filesystems the directory (metadata) is a just a special file, so it can grow in the same way the regular data files grow. On other filesystems some master metadata block has a fixed size which is pre-allocated during file system formatting. In this case the file system can become full before files take all available space.

On a side note, is there a reason to reinvent the wheel (custom file system for private needs)? There exist some implementations of in-file virtual file systems which are similar to archives, but provide more functionality. One of examples is our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/).

Comment: Hi Eugene, I am looking for a challenge. I have also heard of an approach where the metadata section grows towards the end of the disk and the files sections grows towards the metadata section. What do you think of that approach? And thank you for your kind offer, but I want to try my best and come up with my own solution. :)

Comment: @Paterman yes, the approach you describe sounds very interesting and viable too (for fixed size disks). Yet it has a disadvantage in your particular scenario - you would need to fix the size of the storage. In opposite, having everything as sequences of clusters would allow you to grow or shrink your storage as needed. Our SolFS uses the second approach and this lets us have containers of variable length.

Comment: I see. Yes, I do not want to set a fixed size of my archive files. Another idea I had is to put the metadata after the file data, and before saving the archive, copy the whole metadata to memory, let the files overwrite the existing section, and store metadata again in the file. What do you think?

Comment: @Pateman such approach is quite hard and, worse, it's error-prone, especially in case of application, OS or hardware error or failure.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a manifest containing the file list, archive name, and or password and then have all the files listed there

if you can make the files smaller than that's even better!